# Flexible array member (c99) inside a structure

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I've being using this code a while now, and it works fine, but it gave me some headache to implement it. It uses Flexible Array Member (FAM) aka Struct Hack. Now that C99 has the possibility of using Variable Length Array (VLA), I wonder how can I take advantage in this piece?

```
typedef struct nO
{
    int oper;              /* some operator */
    int nops;              /* number of args */
    struct nO *ptn[1];     /* expansible array <=== HERE */
} nodoOper;

nodoOper *operator(int o, int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    nodoOper *tn;
    size_t tam;
    int i;

    tam = sizeof(nodoOper) + (n - 1) * sizeof(nodoOper *); /* <=== AND HERE */

    if((tn=malloc(tam))==NULL)
        yyerror("Memory fault (cod. 4)");

    tn->oper = o;
    tn->nops = n;
    va_start(ap, n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        tn->ptn[i] = va_arg(ap, nodoOper*);
    va_end(ap);
    return tn;
}
```

(I've simplified the whole struct and code here, because it uses two more structs that is not important to the question, so maybe this example has bugs )

Now, the struct definition is in a header file (.h), and the code create a syntax tree for a compiler. How can I change the array to use variable length?

Thanks!
Beco.

Edited: rolling back the last editon to Flexible Array Member.

2nd edition. Suppose I add inside the function this piece of code:

```
struct nOp
{
    int oper;             /* some operator */
    int nops;             /* number of args */
    struct nOp *ptn[n];   /* Variable Length Array (VLA) */
};
struct nOp tnop;
struct nOp *tn2;

tn2 = &tnop;
return tn2;
```

First problem I see, I'm returning a pointer to a local variable. But beside that, is the way fruitful? 
Thanks

Comment: Now that I learned that Flexible Array Member (FAM) is synonymous of Struct Hack, and that it was already what I've done, it is clear to me that the intention of this question is to find another way around using the other tool C99 gaves us called Variable Length Array (VLA). If that is not possible, well... ok, we keep the old way that was already implemented.

Comment: If you decide to keep the "old way", you might consider using `offsetof(nodoOper, ptn) + n * sizeof(nodoOper *)` to calculate the size. That way you don't need to remember to subtract `1`. That way you don't depend on what is specified between `[]` in the array declaration at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's not variable-length arrays that you want to use here, but the `struct` hack, aka "incomplete types", aka the "flexible array member":

```
typedef struct nO
{
    int oper;
    int nops;
    struct nO *ptn[];  // <== look ma, no index!
} nodoOper;

// skip a bit
// no more (n-1) --------\
tam = sizeof(nodoOper) + n * sizeof(nodoOper *);
```

Only the last member of a `struct` may be "flexible".

Variable-length arrays are a different feature:

```
void foo(int size)
{
    float a[size];               // run-time stack allocation
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(a));  // and run-time sizeof (yuck)
}
```

(Oh, and these things are called arrays, not matrices.)

Comment: "Oh, and these things are called arrays, not matrices" -- haha

Comment: :) Ok! I'll correct the post. As @pmg said, the name is important to help searches in the net.

Comment: Thanks larsmans, but it still needs malloc. My intention was to eliminate malloc at all. Is there another option?

Comment: @Dr Beco: no, you can't get rid of `malloc` this way. You can get rid of `malloc` if you do use a VLA after all, but that won't work in a `struct`.

Comment: @larsman, `tam` is supposed the size to be malloced? This is a bit wrong...  `sizeof(nodoOper) + n * sizeof(struct nO*)` or even better `offsetof(nodoOper, ptn) + n * sizeof(struct nO*)` or even better the really correct formula of the `max` of that and `sizeof(nodoOper)`.

Comment: What is wrong with `struct s { int n; struct s *d[m]; }; struct s si;`?

Comment: @Jens: sorry, I don't follow. Did you take into account the `typedef struct nO nodoOper` (without `*`)?

Comment: Yes, `tam` is the total to be malloced.

Comment: @Dr Beco: that works sometimes, but where does the `m` come from? It's not in scope unless you declare the `struct` in a function. But then, you can't use the `struct` outside of that function.

Comment: Can `tam` be rewritten as: `tam = sizeof(nodoOper) + sizeof(struct nO *[m]);`? Or even better: `tam = sizeof(nodoOper) + sizeof(nodoOper *[m]);`?

Comment: Regarding the scope problem, now I understand why you chose to keep malloc. It's a small area here. I'll put another piece of code that came to my mind in the end of the question. I hope we can clarify this part. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Dr Beco: read it. You signal the first problem yourself: returning a pointer to something on the stack, which leads straight down to the 9 circles of undefined behavior. The second problems is that you're returning a `nOp`, which isn't a `nO`. Just use `malloc`.

Comment: @larsman, argh I didn't notice that `struct nO` is the same as `nodoOper`, my bad. But the second part is valid, I think, but probably not relevant for the different sizes and offsets may have, here.

Answer (score 0):

The `C` name for that construction is "flexible array member" (it might help your searches), *or "struct hack" before C99*.

Look at 6.7.2.1 in the [Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf); there is example usage in the text.

---

You may also be interested in "Variable Length Arrays". See 6.7.5.2 in The Standard.

Comment: I might have committed a mistake when editing. I think the correct is Variable Length Arrays now.

Comment: Also listed in the index under "`struct` hack" :)

Comment: Definitely it is not a case of flexible array member.

Comment: I think you have a FAM, @DrBeco. The example in larsmans answer should get you easily started.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many editions. I'm done editing the question title. I'm asking for help for something I even don't know the name. Sorry again guys.

Comment: Yes, this is a case of FAM, not VLA. VLA serves an entirely different purpose, that I've also explained in my post. @Dr Beco: that's alright. You're here to learn, like the rest of us :)