# Different Unallocated Memory Behaviour Between Visual Studio Versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, memory-management, compiler-errors

i'm having a weird situation. i'm trying to implement a 10+ years old pci camera device SDK to my camera management software. Manifacturer no longer in business and i have no chance to get official help. So here I am, looking for some help to my ugly problem.

SDK comes with `Visual Studio 6.0` samples. One of the include files has a structure ending with a one byte array like below;

```
typedef struct AVData {
    ...  
    BYTE audioVideoData[1];
}AVDATA, *PAVDATA;
```

But this single byte allocated byte array receives video frames and weird enough, it works fine with Visual Studio 6.0 version. If I try it with Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010, i start getting `Memory Access Violation` error messages which actully makes sense since it shouldn't be possible to allocate space to a fixed size array afterwards, no? But same code runs fine with VS 6.0?! It's probably caused by either compiler or c++ runtime differences but i'm not very experienced on this subject so it's hard to tell the certain reason for me.

I tried changing the size to an expected maximum number of bytes like below;

```
typedef struct AVData {
    ...  
    BYTE audioVideoData[20000];
}AVDATA, *PAVDATA;
```

This helped it get working but from time to time i get memory access violation problems when trying to destroy the decoder object of the library.

There is something definitely wrong with this. I don't have the source codes of the SDK, only the DLL, Lib and Header files. My questions are:

1) Is it really legal to allocate space to a fixed size array in Visual Studio 6.0 version?

2) Is there any possible way (a compiler option etc.) to make the same code work with newer VS versions / C++ runtimes?

3) Since my workaround of editing the header file works up to a point but still having problems, do you know any better way to get around of this problem?

Comment: I guess the problem should be somewhere else. The array size shouldn't be a problem here, it is not intent to be an upper bound.

Comment: It's called a flexible array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478706/flexible-array-member-c99-inside-a-structure

Comment: But why do we get the Memory Access Violation then? If I create a new object from this structure, wouldn't it be created with the size of 1 (+ rest of the structure elements)? So, how can we store more than one byte to audioVideoData array afterwards? Is it possible to reallocate memory to a fixed size array? Since it works with VS 6.0 version, it might be possible earlier but what about VS 2005+?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not allocating these structs correctly. They have to be allocated with malloc as per the comments and answers.  You need to revisit the documentation for this library.

Comment: @David: Problem is, even their own SDK samples generates the same errors with new Visual Studio versions. Allocation part is done inside of the SDK functions. It's not up to me. I'm trying to find a magical workaround with no luck so far.

Comment: OK, but you've got a pretty clear answer regarding the trick of declaring an array of length 1, but then allocating different amounts of space at runtime. Without any more information from you, you aren't very likely to get any more help here.

Comment: Accepting an answer is not a problem, i already did. But my problem is not solved. What to do now? Reverse engineering? :) The only solution comes to my mind is to write an ActiveX DLL using Visual Studio 6.0 and use it from the new c++ runtime. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC its an old trick to create a struct that is variable in size.

consider

```
struct {
  int len;
  char name[1];
} s;
```

the 'name' can now be of variable length if the appropriate allocation is done and it will be sequentially laid out in memory :

```
char* foo = "abc";
int len = strlen(foo);

struct s* p = malloc( sizeof(int) + len + 1 );

p->len = len;
strcpy(p->name, foo );
```

I think the above should work fine in newer versions of visual studio as well, maybe it is a matter of packing, have you done #pragma pack(1) to get structs on byte boundaries? I know that VS6 had that as default.

Comment: even your answer didn't solve my problem including the pragma trick, your answer is correct and my problem seems unsolvable at the moment.

Comment: if i were you i would try with a much larger buffer, a lot of happened since 10 years ago, especially speed. maybe there is some other issue unrelated to the struct. if increasing the buffer decreases the memory access errors you may be on to some timing error instead.

Answer (score 3):

A one-element array in a C structure like this often means that the size is unknown until runtime. (For a Windows example, see [BITMAPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183375.aspx).)

Usually, there will be some other information (possibly in the struct) that tells you how large the buffer needs to be. You would never allocate one of these directly, but instead allocate the right size block of memory, then cast it:

```
int size = /* calculate frame size somehow */
AVDATA * data = (AVDATA*) malloc(sizeof(AVDATA) + size);
// use data->audioVideoData
```

Answer (score 1):

The code almost certainly exhibits undefined behaviour in some way, and there is no way to fix this except to fix the interface or source code of the SDK. As it is no longer in business, this is impossible.

Comment: Technically, you're right -- it is UB. Realistically, the struct hack has been common enough for long enough that chances of getting unexpected results when you use it "correctly" are essentially nonexistent. That's unlikely to change with most compilers since C99 and newer bless this as a "flexible array member".

Comment: I don't think this answer makes sense in context. "UB" removes restrictions on how an arbitrary compiler can deal with it. But we know that the library is compiled with VC6, and will never be compiled with another compiler, so the behavior is already set in stone.