# Adding elements to Flexible Array Members

Tags: c, flexible-array-member

I've read and looked at some example of flexible array members but I am not exactly sure how to add and read elements of this variable length array.

```
typedef struct School {
    char *name;
    char *courses[]; //Flexible Array Member
} School;
```

1) Can someone please show me an example of how I can add an element to this Flexible Length Member and print it after it is stored.

2) I also would like to know how to malloc it correctly. Based on what I have read about Flexible Array Members, we would need to add more space for the flexible array member and can't just use `sizeof(School);`. My only issue is how do I know how much do add for that flexible member.

Comment: You will find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478706/flexible-array-member-c99-inside-a-structure?rq=1

Comment: You need to either add struct member for the actual number of `courses` allocated for the structure or make the `courses` array end with a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Allocate the structure with `malloc(sizeof(School) + n * sizeof(char*))`

Comment: @chqrlie shouldnt it end with a null anyways since it is a array?

Comment: No, arrays do not necessarily end with a `NULL`, it is a matter of convention: either you know how many elements are allocated for the array and you give this information to all users of the structure, or you add a final `NULL` element when you allocate the array and users will look for the `NULL` element.

Comment: @chqrlie Could you please show me an example of how I could add to the array, I looked at the link but am still a bit confused as to how I would do it in this char array.

Comment: You cannot add to the array once the structure is allocated.  The number of elements in the array is fixed at the time of allocation.  This allocation must be dynamic.

Comment: @chqrlie I'm sorry if i didn't explain well. But I meant how to add an element to the array (my original question 1) ) because I didn't fully understand how to add elements to my char array. Sorry for the misunderstanding :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `struct` to add the number of courses present in the allocated structure:

```
typedef struct School {
    char *name;
    int ncourses;
    char *courses[]; //Flexible Array Member
} School;
```

Say you have 2 schools, one with 3 courses, one with 2.  You would allocate the structures this way:

```
School *mc = malloc(offsetof(struct School, courses) + 3 * sizeof(char *));
mc->name = strdup("Math College");
mc->ncourses = 3;
mc->courses[0] = strdup("Math 101");
mc->courses[1] = strdup("Math 102");
mc->courses[2] = strdup("Math 103");

School *ps = malloc(offsetof(struct School, courses) + 2 * sizeof(char *));
ps->name = strdup("Psycho School");
ps->ncourses = 2;
ps->courses[0] = strdup("Psycho 101");
ps->courses[1] = strdup("Unknown 404");
```

As you can see, elements of the variable array are accessed like any other array elements.  The `malloc` call allocates the appropriate size in bytes for the struct members and the array elements (here `char *` pointers), that are located at the end of the structure.

You could use a generic function to allocate and initialize such structures:

```
School create_school(const char *school_name, int ncourses, char *courses[]) {
    School *sp = malloc(offsetof(struct School, courses) + ncourses * sizeof(char *));
    sp->name = strdup(school_name);
    sp->ncourses = ncourses;
    for (int i = 0; i < ncourses; i++) {
        sp->courses[i] = strdup(courses[i]);
    }
    return sp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I understand now. Just one quick question, would it be possible just to allocate the memory for the struct first and then afterwards realloc the extra needed for the flexible array?

Comment: @Billy: yes that would be possible, but you would need to update the pointers that refer to this structure everywhere.  It may not be so easy if such a pointer was passed to a function in your call chain.  Just updating your caller's local variable requires that it passes you a pointer to them.

Answer (score 0):

The exact formula for computing the required size of your structure is:

```
size_t need = offsetof(struct School, courses) + num_courses * sizeof(char *);
```

Note the use of `offsetof`. Some people use `sizeof`, but this can introduce memory overhead due to structure padding.

Comment: @michaelmaeyer could you please show me how to add an elemet to the array. Im a still a bit confused about that.

Comment: The use of `offsetof()` works, but `sizeof` does not "introduce memory overhead due to structure padding".   The C standard says, for the case of flexible array members, that "the size of the structure shall be equal to the offset of the last element of an otherwise identical structure that replaces the flexible array member with an array of unspecified length."     Which means that `sizeof(struct School)` and `offsetof(struct School, courses)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the technique is to dynamically allocate enough memory for the struct, plus the elements of the last array.

```
School *data = malloc(sizeof(*data) + number * sizeof(*(data->courses)));

for (i = 0; i < number; ++i)
{
     const char hello[] = "Hello";
     data->courses[i] = malloc(strlen(hello) + 1));   /* sizeof char is 1 by definition */
     strcpy(courses[i], hello);
}
```